# Can I customize automatic event handler generation in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events, code-completion

When you subscribe to an event in code, Visual Studio automatically completes the code after `+=` and generates the appropriate event handler:

```
button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
//              ↑_____auto generated code_____↑
```

Notice how it explicitly creates the delegate instance: even though method groups are implicitly convertible to delegates since C# 2, the IDE behavior still hasn't changed in VS2010.

So I'd like to know, is there a way to generate code like this instead?

```
button.Click += button_Click;
```

---

EDIT
just to make things clear to everyone: the code above is *not* in a designer file (I wouldn't care which syntax is used if it was the case). It's the snippet that is triggered when you type `+=` after an event name and press <kbd>TAB</kbd>

---

EDIT2
I reported this as a [suggestion on Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/632300/auto-generated-event-handlers-should-use-implicit-conversion-of-method-group-to-delegate), you can vote for it if you also want the current behavior to be changed

Comment: Why do you assume this code is in a designer file? Don't you ever manually subscribe to an event? I don't care about code that is in designer files, but I want *my* code to be as readable as possible. The implicit conversion from method group to delegate seems much more readable to me, the explicit delegate instantiation just adds noise.

Comment: (slightly ot) If you `button.Click -= button_Click` does that work the same way?

Comment: @Greg, not it doesn't... It would be nice, but I can live with it ;)

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were talking about hooking events through the UI. I have just always deleted the new WhateverEventHandler manually, never really thought about changing it.

Comment: @Ed, yes, that's what I do too (Resharper makes it easy, just type Alt+Enter). It's just annoying that VS continues to call the delegate constructor even though it's been unnecessary for years...

Comment: I really dont't see any reason for customizing this. What studio provides after you click tab (once or twice) is a good starting point to implement your handler the way you like.

Comment: @bakopanos costas, did you actually read the question ? I don't care about what is in the handler, I just don't want the explicit call to the delegate constructor, since it's unnecessary and just adds noise

Comment: If you agree with Thomas, please vote for this on the Connect link provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [suggestion on Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/632300/auto-generated-event-handlers-should-use-implicit-conversion-of-method-group-to-delegate) has been marked as fixed, so the new behavior should be included in the next public build of VS11.

EDIT: just checked, it is indeed included in the beta.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for clarifying your question. Unfortunately, there isn't a way to configure or customize the event hookup code that is generated by the C# language service. To make matters worse, the Generate Method Stub feature won't work on an event hookup either -- though it should, and that is already fixed for the next release of Visual Studio.

Sorry that there isn't a better story for this particular feature. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I use [this](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/14f62cb9-b559-4bad-9388-37da2150e238) extension for Visual Studio since a couple of years.