# Configure VS 2010 so that it doesn't add new EventHandler(...); when adding an EventHandler via +=

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I customize automatic event handler generation in Visual Studio ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471593/can-i-customize-automatic-event-handler-generation-in-visual-studio)

Can I configure VS2010 Intellisense so that it does this:

```
SomeEvent += Some_Method;
```

instead of this:

```
SomeEvent += new EventHandler(Some_Method);
```

when adding an EventHandler via += and pressing the Shift key?

I understand that this doesn't make any difference as far as the generated IL is concerned but I personally much prefer the first version. It is easier to read and I don't have to go and fix the += / -= calls when I go and change the EventHandler type to something different.

Comment: No option for this.  It really doesn't matter which flavor you use, they produce the same IL.

Comment: I wish I could suck out the underscore and get rid of the new syntax.

Comment: Duplicate of [Can I customize automatic event handler generation in Visual Studio ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471593/can-i-customize-automatic-event-handler-generation-in-visual-studio) - there is a [connect article](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/632300/auto-generated-event-handlers-should-use-implicit-conversion-of-method-group-to-delegate) linked to in that question in which Microsoft have refused to fix it.

Comment: thanks adrianbanks, didn't realize that this has been asked before. voted to close.

Comment: @adrian: "We're too close to releasing our service pack, maybe next version" isn't the same as refusing to fix it.  It is rather unfortunate that MS Connect doesn't have a "deferred" status instead of just closing the issue.  Anyway, vote it up up up.

Comment: @Ben: True, but marking as WontFix for SP1 is as good as realistically saying it won't be fixed in VS2010 (and I have already up-voted it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, sorry.  I just go with the default behavior and then delete the extra fluff after it's stubbed out the method for me.